# Transforms Europe PMC RESTful "search" responses to source/external-id lists

Tags: javascript, rest, api, europepmc

I would like to use [Europe PMC RESTful API](https://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService) to transforms "search" responses to source/external-id lists, with one-line per record text.

Any suggestions / examples (in JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to transform the response you get from the Europe PMC RESTful API.

You can find [an example written in Vue.js on JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/diposav), where you can find the example XSL file, and how to transform the XML response to an ID list in JavaScript as below:

#### Example XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- 
        Script: rest2ids.xsl
        Version: 1.0
        Summary: Transforms Europe PMC RESTful "search" responses to source/external-id lists, with one-line per record text.
        Notes: Either resulttype=lite or resulttype=core paramater can used
    -->
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
   <xsl:param name="idMode" select="1" />
   <!-- 1 = Format IDs as on the front end, 2 = Format IDs for using Excel to generate External Links data -->
   <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="/responseWrapper/resultList/result">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$idMode=1 and source/text()='MED'">
               <xsl:text>PMID</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$idMode=1 and (source/text()='PMC')">
               <xsl:text>PMCID</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="source/text()" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$idMode=1">
               <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:text />
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:value-of select="id/text()" />
         <!-- Output PMCID -->
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$idMode=1 and source/text()='MED'">
               <xsl:if test="pmcid != ''">
                  <xsl:text>,PMCID:</xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="pmcid/text()" />
               </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise />
         </xsl:choose>
         <!-- End of outputting PMCID -->
         <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
      <title>JS Bin</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app">
         <input type="text" size="70" v-model="url">
         <fieldset>
            <legend>Output</legend>
            <textarea id="output" cols="56" rows="10" v-model="output"></textarea>
         </fieldset>
         <button @click="downloadData">Download</button>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

#### Vue.js

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            url: "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=cancer",
            xhttp: {},
            output: ''
        };
    },
    watch: {
        url: function() {
            this.output = this.transform();
        }
    },
    created() {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            this.xhttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            this.xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadXMLDoc: function(filename) {
            this.xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
            try {
                this.xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document";
            } catch (err) {}
            this.xhttp.send("");
            return this.xhttp.responseXML;
        },
        download: function(filename, text) {
            let element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
            element.setAttribute('download', filename);
            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
            document.body.removeChild(element);
        },
        downloadData: function() {
            this.download('idlist.txt', this.output);
        },
        transform: function() {
            let xml = this.loadXMLDoc(this.url);
            let xsl = this.loadXMLDoc("https://yucigou.github.io/staticfs/xsl/rest2ids.xsl");
            if (window.ActiveXObject || this.xhttp.responseType === "msxml-document") {
                return xml.transformNode(xsl);
            } else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
                // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
                let xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
                xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
                let resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
                return resultDocument.textContent;
            }          
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.output = this.transform();
    }
});
```

When you run this example in a browser, you will see the output:

[image]

You can change the query to see the output being updated, and you can also download it to a file as shown above.